# Google assistant service, how to filter multiple audio responses

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

It's hard to explain but in fact I m trying to code my own library with The Google Assistant Service.

```
me > "set a timer"
GA > "sure, how long"
me > "10 mn"
GA > "ok, timer is set" (1st response)
GA > "Sorry I can't help you" (2nd response)
```

The reaction is normal, because service don't support timer. I want to code my own timer, but no way to keep the first response and block the second. **dialog_state_out.supplemental_display_text** contain only the first one, but the audio core play all the data we have in **audio_out.audio_data**.

How to separe the 2 responses, I don't see disconnection on the data flow and only 1 request done.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is using [custom device actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/device-actions-overview). You can create your own action that will trigger on a query like "set a timer", allowing you to handle custom logic and even support parameters within the query itself.

[This page](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/extend/custom-actions) in the documentation explains how to set them up. You define an action package with your actions. Here's an action for "blinking":

```
"actions": [
    {
        "name": "com.example.actions.BlinkLight",
        "availability": {
            "deviceClasses": [
                {
                    "assistantSdkDevice": {}
                }
            ]
        },
        "intent": {
            "name": "com.example.intents.BlinkLight",
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "number",
                    "type": "SchemaOrg_Number"
                },
                {
                    "name": "speed",
                    "type": "Speed"
                }
            ],
            "trigger": {
                "queryPatterns": [
                    "blink ($Speed:speed)? $SchemaOrg_Number:number times",
                    "blink $SchemaOrg_Number:number times ($Speed:speed)?"
                ]
            }
        },
        "fulfillment": {
            "staticFulfillment": {
                "templatedResponse": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "simpleResponse": {
                                "textToSpeech": "Blinking $number times"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "deviceExecution": {
                                "command": "com.example.commands.BlinkLight",
                                "params": {
                                    "speed": "$speed",
                                    "number": "$number"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
],
```

Comment: Thx, that's the answer I feared ^^. There is too much thing you need to disable and remake to use this sdk. For exemple for this timer, 90% is already done, but unusable, and you need to remake all the function at 100%, it's same for calendar, shopping list, ect .... And idk what can happen, if i use an "order" for my device action that is aleady managed out of the box by the GA. I will wait some days, but I think I will not have better answer.